# Cache eviction not working without key, and method has no arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I bumped into this interesting Spring Boot Cache eviction scenario where I have a no-arg method with `@Cacheable("users")` and I have another method with `@CacheEvict("users")`.

```
@Cacheable(value = "users")
public List<String> getUsers() {
    return myRepo.getUsers();
}

@CacheEvict(value = "users")
public void createUser(User user) {
    myRepo.createUser(user);
}
```

My assumption is whenever I call `createUser()` method the "users" cache will be evicted and next time when I call `getUsers()` it will call `myRepo.getUsers()`. But I noticed "users" cache is not evicted and `myRepo.getUsers()` not getting called.

Upon trial and error I managed to fix this issue by specifying **key** as follows:

```
@Cacheable(value = "users", key="'users'")
public List<String> getUsers() {
    return myRepo.getUsers();
}

@CacheEvict(value = "users", key="'users'")
public void createUser(User user) {
    myRepo.createUser(user);
}
```

Is this expected behaviour? Shouldn't it evict all entries in "users" cache by just mentioning **@CacheEvict(value = "users")**?

Comment: Is it working for method with some argument? question Title seems  misleading

Comment: did you try @CacheEvict(value = "users" allEntries = true)

Comment: Adding allEntries = true would do the trick, but if we don't specify a key shouldn't it evict all?

Comment: The cache is caching based on the key or a generated one. It will cache the result of the method as is. So in your case it will store a `List` of `User` objects. It will NOT store the individual users a a key/value pair. By default the cache eviction will evict the same element (based on key) as being updated. As you have a different key nothing will be evicted. Which is what you see by hardcoding a key in the annotations. And no the default isn't if nothing matches empty the whole cache, the default is remove the matching elements. Why should it evict something that isn't cached?

Comment: Thanks for clarification M. Deinum.

Answer (score 0):

you must add `allEntries=true` in the `CacheEvict` annotation as below to enable evicting everything inside the cache:

> @CacheEvict(value = "users", allEntries=true)

default value of `allEntries` is `false`.